# Open Page in ReadOnly mode

Tags: asp.net

I have to open page in read only mode where all the controls are disabled and no body can perform any action on page.

I tried to use Panel / div overlap.

is there any other smart solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a light-box style overlay, I don't think that would work in all cases. For example, you might want to scroll a listbox, or a scrolling div in the page, even if you can't select anything in it. And you also sometimes want to be able to select and copy from a read-only page.

In terms of the rendered HTML, I would opt for using the "readonly" attribute where possible, or the "disabled" attribute if that's more appropriate, or an alternative read-only rendering (for example `select` elements can't be marked as readonly)

Answer (score 1):

### Technique 1

By using jQuery short and smart sytax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var disabled = true/false;
  if (disabled) {
    $('input,select').attr('disabled',disabled);
  }
})
</script>
```

### Technique 2

Use labels instead of controls

Comment: Technique 2 has the advantage of working when javascript is disabled.